# MiKTeX europecv (German) language

Tags: lyx, miktex, german

I'm translating a CV into German, under both OS X and Windows 7 with MiKTeX. The problem is that German doesn't work. I tried French, Italian, Dutch and they all work. Any idea where I should look for a resolution?

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman,nologo]{europecv}
```

I get no errors, nothing, just the result is in English. For the record, `AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\europecv` contains all the expected language templates (`ecvde.def` being the interesting one). I simply copied the German words into `ecven.def` but that's ridiculous.

LE. I'm actually generating the document with LyX. If I export it the language appears as in the code snippet above - `ngerman`. It would seem that `german` is the correct setting; I'm still investigating.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so it would seem that the proper way to use the german template is `german` and not `ngerman`. In LyX, that setting is triggerable by `Document - Settings - Language - German (old spelling)`.

It would be cool to know how to treat the "new" variant of spelling, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

The package documentation:
http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/europecv.pdf

Page 2:

> *Language options*
>
> Important!
>
> The following options **are not related to babel**. See the Notes at the end of this list

Page 3:

> *Notes*
>
> The choice of the language only aﬀects the appearance of the title
> (“Europass Curriculum Vitæ”), the personal information section, the
> spoken language table and the footer with the page number. In some
> cases, it may aﬀects the used alphabet (e.g. in Bulgarian).
> **If you want to use the hyphenation patterns for the language(s) of your
> choice, you must include the babel package in your document.**

Try to add `ngerman`:

http://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/German.html

> Eingebunden werden sie mit folgendem Befehl
>
> \usepackage{german} bzw. \usepackage{ngerman}
>
> Alternativ über das babel Paket
>
> \usepackage[german]{babel} bzw. \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
>
> Hierbei wird german bzw. ngerman als Option des Paketes babel gesetzt.

I personally prefer the method

```
\usepackage{german}
```